# Issue updating SQL Server with Excel 2016 on Workbook_Activate()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update SQL Server using Excel on Workbook_Activate() that grabs the data and sends a reply of `1` in the `Grabbed` field after the data has been loaded to the sheet. It seems like the code isn't executing.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql As String

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim PN As String
Dim partid As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername; Database=CI; UID=userID; PWD=UserPassword"
cn.Open strConn

partid = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G2").Value

strSql = "UPDATE dbo.OHW_Schedule SET Grabbed = '1' WHERE ID = '" & partid & "' "

cn.Execute strSql

End Sub
```

when I go through the code line by line everything works fine. I've tried adding a DoEvents after the refresh but still no luck. I've also tried using Workbook_Open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have often found that you need to trigger your ADODB connections in a seperate proceedure, called via `Application.OnTime Now(), "ProceedureName"` so that Excel finishes Opening & allocating References first and the update happens immediately after.

E.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnTime Now(), "ThisWorkbook.UpdateData"
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateData()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, strSql As String
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim strConn As String, partid As Integer

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Try to avoid ActiveWorkbook wherever possible!

    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to DB"
    strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername; Database=CI; UID=userID; PWD=UserPassword"
    cn.Open strConn

    partid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G2").Value 'Fully Qualify your Worksheets

    Application.StatusBar = "Running Update"
    strSql = "UPDATE dbo.OHW_Schedule SET Grabbed = '1' WHERE ID = '" & partid & "' "

    cn.Execute strSql

    Application.StatusBar = "Disconnecting from DB"
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel is still trying to update before the data is loaded. I've tried adding a couple of seconds nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Does running `UpdateData` manually (by pressing [F5] or the green "Run" button) work correctly?

Comment: So is the problem that `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` is refreshing in the Background, and not waiting until complete before the macro triggers?  If so, try putting it *before* the `Application.OnTime` or put `DoEvents` **immediately** after the `RefreshAll` line

Comment: Tried that still no help. I found out the problem for some reason I enabled background refresh, so disabling that makes the code work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in the other answer you said that you had tried adding a couple of secounds, i wasn't completely sure what you meant by that, but I'm guessing you have already attempted something like this?

Change the 20 seconds to what ever you feel like

```
Private Sub workbook_activate()
Dim time_delay As Date
time_delay = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:20")
Application.OnTime time_delay, "thisworkbook.updatetable"
End Sub


Private Sub updatetable()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql As String

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim PN As String
Dim partid As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername; Database=CI; UID=userID; PWD=UserPassword"
cn.Open strConn

partid = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G2").Value

strSql = "UPDATE dbo.OHW_Schedule SET Grabbed = '1' WHERE ID = '" & partid & "' "

cn.Execute strSql

End Sub
```

Comment: If you put a msgbox in there, does the msgbox run?

Comment: Yes the message box runs. The issue is the code is trying to run before the data has finished loading. I've also tried adding a DoEvents still no luck.

Comment: I see, sorry I misread the question and kind of omitted that line in my mind. Let me have a look and I'll update my answer